# Erase a subview

Tags: iphone, view, alpha, erase

If I want to erase a subview, is it done when I put mysubview.alpha = 0;?
Or do I have to do anything else? 
Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by erase? Do you want to remove it completely remove it from main view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "erase" a subview, just release it ;) It you put it's alpha value to 0, it is only hidden.
As said in comment, you also have to remove it from superview (`[myView removeFromSuperview]`).

Comment: [mySubview removeFromSuperview] does indeed release the view as well as removing it from its container view.

Comment: I have an animation just before this, now, with the remove, animation is not working, can you tell me why? thank you again

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove it do so using

```
[mySubview removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use:-

```
[*yoursubviewname* removeFromSuperView];
```